# Swift: Convenience initializers - Self used before self.init call

Tags: ios, swift, initialization

We are getting the following error on the convenience method below:

> Self used before self.init call

```
class MyClass {
    var id : Int        
    var desc : String

    init?(id : Int, desc : String) {
        self.id = id
        self.desc = desc
    }

    convenience init?(id : Int?) {
        guard let x = id else {
            return
        }
        self.init(id : x, desc : "Blah")
    }
}
```

How can we implement this type of behavior in Swift?

Comment: Just `return nil`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As Leo already pointed out, the quickest way of appeasing the compiler is to return nil inside the guard statement.

```
convenience init?(id : Int?) {
    guard let x = id else {
        return nil
    }
    self.init(id: x, desc: "Blah")
}
```

Unless there is a specific reason to do so, you can also avoid using a failable initializer in the first place.`init(id : Int, desc : String)` compiles just fine.